# Create appendix with R-code in rmarkdown/knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is it possible to get all of the code in a appendix. Say I have two chunks in a document and then some text.

````
```{r, echo=TRUE}
x <- 4+5
x
```  
Above is X output.

```{r, echo=TRUE}
y <- 22+325
y
```   

Above is Y output.
````

---

And then I want all of the code in a appendix but shown as if I put `eval=FALSE` in the chunk.

Something like this

````
```{r, SHOW_ALL_CODE=TRUE}
```
````

Expected output:

```
Chunk_1
x <- 4+5  
x

Chunk_2  
y <- 22+325  
y
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`knitr::purl()` can extract all R code from a markdown file into an R script. You can add that as an appendix.

````
## appendix

```{r code=readLines(knitr::purl('~/path/to/file.Rmd', documentation = 0)), eval = FALSE}

```
````

Comment: This is really good. Is it possible to separate the chunks? Or give a title?
Now I have to give a title in the code using `# comments`.

Comment: Set `documentation = 1`. Then the section titles will be added as comments. See `?purl` for the details.

Answer (score 24):

Another possibility:

````
### Appendix 
```{r, ref.label=knitr::all_labels(),echo=TRUE,eval=FALSE}
```
````

as suggested by [Yihui's nice example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/073-code-appendix.Rnw)

Comment: Best answer as one does not need to include the file path.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a reference to your initial chunks, but then change the options:

````
main text

```{r blah, echo = FALSE}
summary(cars)
```

appendix

```{r blah2, ref.label='blah', eval = FALSE}
```
````

Which will give:

[image]

Comment: From time to time I have/want to put the code for certain functions in the appendix of a report. 
I am cognisant that the original question was about "all" code chunks. And ultimately, this answers is not providing "all" chunks. It is an intuitive way to add things to the appendix of a Rmd document and allows to write surrounding text.
Other answers show how to do this programmatically. Yihui has a post on working with knitr::all_labels and subsetting or using appendix = TRUE. 
For my future me: think about what you want to do with the code in the appendix! This one can take you far.